# numpy get multiple indices on numbers for multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two arrays:

```
array_1 =  np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15]])
```

and

```
array_2 =  np.array([[2,3,5], [6,8,9], [12,13,14]])
```

I want to have the row-based indices for the values of array_2 on array_1, akas

```
np.array([[1,2,4], [0,2,3], [1,2,3]])
```

as the desired output.

How should I proceed with numpy functions?

Comment: How do you specify the indices you want to pick from the rows of `array_1`?

Comment: For instance for the first row
in array_1 it is [1,2,3,4,5], and array_2 it is [2,3,5]
I just want the location of array_2 elements on array_1

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this ? :**

```
import numpy as np

array_1 =  np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15]])
array_2 =  np.array([[2,3,5], [6,8,9], [12,13,14]])

result = {}

for index, list_val in np.ndenumerate(array_2):
    print(f'Finding: {list_val} in {array_1[index[0]]}')
    print()
    index_in_array_1 = np.where(array_1[index[0]] == list_val )
    print(f'match at : {index_in_array_1}')
    print()
```

**Result:**

[image]